# refactoring nested if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some code that looks similar to the code below. I feel that there should be a simpler way to do what it does. My main concern is the call to getDataB() in both if and else blocks of the (!dataA.isEmpty()) condition.

```
    DataA dataA = getDataA();

    if (!dataA.isEmpty()) {

        if (dataA.getStatus() == Status.FINAL) {
            // process finalized dataA
        }

        if (dataA.getStatus() == Status.RECEIVED) {
            DataB dataB = getDataB();
            if (!dataB.isEmpty()) {
                dataA.setStatus(dataB.getStatus());
                // process dataA with updated status from dataB
            }
        }

        if (dataA.getStatus() == STATUS.IN_PROGRESS) {
            // process in progress dataA
        }

    // empty dataA
    } else {
        Datab dataB = getDataB();
        if (!dataB.isEmpty()) {
            // process dataB
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as a side note, in your `if` statements `Status` or `STATUS` should probably have a consistent capitalisation.

Answer (score 1):

There is still room for improvement, but as an initial refactoring you can do something like this:

```
// I like to get rid of the negations, assuming that DataA and DataB are your objects.
// I would normally declare a method with more meaning, like hasData(), otherwise just use the negation and the isEmpty.

DataA dataA = getDataA();
DataB dataB = getDataB();

// When DataA has data
if (dataA.hasData()) {  
    Status statusA = dataA.getStatus(); 

    switch(statusA) {
        case Status.FINAL:
            // process finalized dataA
            break;
        case Status.RECEIVED:
            if (dataB.hasData()) {
                dataA.setStatus(dataB.getStatus());
                // process dataA with updated status from dataB
            }
            break; // If you want to process dataA in progress after setting the dataB status in A, then remove this break.
        case Status.IN_PROGRESS:
            // process in progress dataA
            break;          
    }

// When DataB has data
} else if (dataB.hasData()) {
    // process dataB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, take the processing of `dataB` (present in the bottom else in your code) out in its own function like:

```
private void processDataB() {
    DataB dataB = getDataB();
    if (dataB.isEmpty()) return;
    // process dataB
}
```

Notice how we inverted the `if` condition to return from the method if `dataB` is empty.

Next, apply the same inverting of `if` to the main code. The new code will look like:

```
DataA dataA = getDataA();
if (dataA.isEmpty()) { //Inverted the test.
    processDataB();
    return;
}

if (dataA.getStatus() == Status.FINAL) {
    // process finalized dataA
}

if (dataA.getStatus() == Status.RECEIVED) {
    DataB dataB = getDataB();
    if (!dataB.isEmpty()) {
        dataA.setStatus(dataB.getStatus());
        // process dataA with updated status from dataB
    }
}

if (dataA.getStatus() == STATUS.IN_PROGRESS) {
    // process in progress dataA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the duplicate logic to a method that accepts a lambda:

```
void processDataB(Consumer<DataB> action) {
    DataB dataB = getDataB();
    if (!dataB.isEmpty()) {
        action.accept(dataB);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
//...
    if (dataA.getStatus() == Status.RECEIVED) {
        processDataB(dataB -> {
            dataA.setStatus(dataB.getStatus());
            // process dataA with updated status from dataB
        });
    }
//...
} else {
    processDataB(dataB ->
        // process dataB
    });
}
```